# how to make a installation like window in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am making software and want to make a user interface for installation. I would appriciate if anyone could give me any tips, hints, or links which would get em started

I want my installation window to look like this

[image]

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Comment: For Windows you have WiX (and a number of other solutions)

Answer (score 1):

There a are lots of tools to generate Installer tools for Windows.

I have had good experience with WiX[1] and InnoSetup[2] so far. NSIS[3] is also an alternative.

WiX uses XML to define your installer, InnoSetup uses the Pascal language.

[1] http://wixtoolset.org/

[2] http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

[3] http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: You were faster than me:-) However, you should mention that nsis and inno setup both create "classic" setups (Setup.exe) whereas wix creates Windows installer (.msi)

Comment: That's a very good hint, Chris, thank you :)

Comment: and to do than in linux or unix

Comment: On Linux and Unix you will want to use their own package utilities (just like **.msi is on windows). If you must provide a unified way to install everywhere, you can use those java setup utilities for example. Netbeans goes that path. A quick google revealed http://izpack.org/